# How should i correctly write the variable for the function, variable name atrName

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I want to update 1 field from my database table. As you can see I am trying to assign the value `vrednost` to `atrName`. My error occurs on this line: `R.+atrName+=` How do I write that line correctly?

```
public bool UpdatePlayerVV(string ime, string atrName, string vrednost)
{
    DataSet1.PlayersDataTable his = Adapter.GetDatapl2(ime);
    if (his.Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    DataSet1.PlayersRow R = his[0];

    if (vrednost == null) { }
    else R.+atrName+= vrednost; 




    int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(R);


    return rowsAffected == 1;
}
```

Comment: i what to do something like this 

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Players set " + atrIm + "='" + vrednost + "' where brojID='1'", conn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use onli brackets

R[variable]=Somevalue;

Answer (score 0):

```
var nw = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTION_STRING"];
int count = 0;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
connection.ConnectionString = nw.ConnectionString;
var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "update Players set...."
connection.Open();
count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: no i don't need that i need in my BLL class , so in code behind i can call the object.UpdatePlayersWW(var,var,var)

Comment: but thats what you asked on your comment. var cmd = connection.CreateCommand(); is the same that  new SqlCommand(..)

Comment: i only ask how to write this correctly

else R.+atrName+= vrednost;

Comment: I think that's it: "update Players set atrName ='" + vrednost + "' where brojID=1"
if atrName is the name of the column, vrednost the variable with the value to update and brojID = 1 where you want to update

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
R[atrName] += vrednost;
```